# Firebase Google sign-in as Users in Authentication

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app.

I've succesfully implemented Google sign-in thanks to the NuGet [Plugin.GoogleClient](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin).

The problem is when I want to modify the Firebase project rules so only authenticated users can access to the Cloud Firestore database. In my Firebase console appears that the project doesn't have any user:

[image: console1]

But in the app I'm using my Google account with no problem:

[image]

How can I authenticate Google signed-in accounts so they can appear in Users, so I can modify the rules of the Cloud Firestore?

Edit: these are my Firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

Immediately after I sign in with Google, I get `Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestoreException: 'PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.'`.

However, if I set the rules to be just `true`, I can use my Google account with no problems, but for what the exception states, it isn't authenticated (?).

Answer (score 1):

To allow only authenticated users access to the data in Cloud Firestore, have a look at the documentation on [security rules for all authenticated users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#all_authenticated_users). From there:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This will still work even when you don't see the user in the Firebase console. As long as they have a Firebase ID token, that token will be checked in these security rules.

Comment: I published that rule but I can't read data. Immediately after I sign in with Google, I get the exception `Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestoreException: 'PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.'`. Can you explain me how to add or get the Firebase ID token you mention?

Comment: Signing in with Google does not automatically then also sign you in with Firebase. You'll need to use the credentials you get back from Google sign-in to then sing in with Firebase.

Comment: Do you know how to do that in Xamarin?

Comment: From scannning a few blog posts ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-auth-on-xamarin-forms-171432aa3d76)), it seems that would be very similar to how it works in the Android SDK: `FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync` Also see: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/af4d43bc6812315b2569d511da007cde0c2fb83c/source/com.google.firebase/firebase-auth/Additions/Additions.cs#L23