# How to send authentication token with requests using Plugin.Firestore in xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access my firebase project with a cross-platform app made in Xamarin for Visual Studio. I am using the `Plugin.CloudFirestore` NuGet package for accessing the database and the `FirebaseAuthentication.net` NuGet package for handling authentication. I am able to sign up and login users, which works properly. I am able to access the Cloud Firestore database when the rules are open:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

However when I try to use the rules provided by Google to check for authenticated users:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am given the error:

> Plugin.CloudFirestore.CloudFirestoreException: 'PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.'

I believe this is because I am not sending an authentication token with my requests, but I can't seem to figure out how to send this token using `Plugin.CloudFirestore`.

Comment: On other platforms, you don't have to do anything to send an auth token.  It's sent automatically by the SDK when a user is already signed in with Firebase Auth.

Comment: @malcolms123 You could need to use `FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync` to pass e-mail and password as parameters and call a method to authenticate the user and then we return a token. I find one samilar thread that you can take a look:[Firebase Google sign-in as Users in Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641939/firebase-google-sign-in-as-users-in-authentication)

Comment: @Cherry It looks like an actionable information, please post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cherry Bu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717445/cherry-bu-msft):

You could need to use `FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync` to pass e-mail and password as parameters and call a method to authenticate the user and then we return a token. I find [one similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641939/firebase-google-sign-in-as-users-in-authentication) that you can take a look.